# $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies\ \sum \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let $a_n > 0.$ When $\sum a_n$ converges $\sum \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$ converges or not?

For, $$\frac{\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}}{a_n}=\frac {\sqrt{a_{n+1}}} {\sqrt{a_n}}$$

$\because$ By comparison test $\sum \sqrt{a_n}$ converges,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {\sqrt{a_{n+1}}} {\sqrt{a_n}}=1\neq0$$

Therefore by limit comparison test $\sum \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$ converges.

Is this proof correct?

Corrections will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: $\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}} \le \frac12\left(a_n+a_{n+1}\right)$

Comment: The statement "By comparison test $\sum {\sqrt {a_n}}$ converges" is wrong. For example, $\sum{1/n^2}$ converges while $\sum \sqrt{1/n^2}$ doesn't.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\sum b_n c_n \leq \sqrt{\sum b_n^2}\sqrt{\sum c_n^2}$. Now apply this with $b_n = \sqrt{a_n}$ and $c_n = \sqrt{a_{n+1}}$.

Comment: @Chris Drost Thank you, but $a_n \geq \sqrt{a_n}?$

Comment: @UmaMaheswariN.Lenin No. If $0<a_n<1$ then $a_n<\sqrt{a_n}$.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks i got. So i can't use limit comparison theorem here. isn't it?